# Remove fullcalendar event from JSON using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

I want to remove event from Fullcalendar json file using PHP.

For example I have actual two events in my json file:

```
[{"id":1,"title":"TERMIN ZAREZERWOWANY","start":"2016-10-13T07:00","end":"2016-10-13T08:00"},{"id":2,"title":"TERMIN ZAREZERWOWANY","start":"2016-10-14T08:00","end":"2016-10-14T09:00"}]
```

When I click on event, JS remove event from frontend and fire this PHP code (for now I want to remove first event $array_data[0]):

```
if (file_exists('cal.json')) {
            $current_data = file_get_contents('cal.json');
            $array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);

            unset($array_data[0]);

            $new_data = json_encode($array_data);   
                file_put_contents('cal.json', $new_data);

        }
        else
        {
            $error = 'json not exist';
        }
```

After this my new json file looks like:

```
{"1":{"id":2,"title":"TERMIN ZAREZERWOWANY","start":"2016-10-14T08:00","end":"2016-10-14T09:00"}}
```

What I`m doing wrong? What is this {"1":{... in new json file? Please help and sorry for my english ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `unset`, you're unsetting the value of that array key, you're not removing the key.

Instead, use [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) or [`array_pop`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php), which will remove the element from the begining or end of the array, respectively.

```
$current_data = file_get_contents('cal.json');
$array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);
array_shift($array_data);
$new_data = json_encode($array_data);   
file_put_contents('cal.json', $new_data);
```

Comment: But the next step is to remove the element from $array_data which is equal to specific "id"... how can I do that?

Comment: @sunnyluk - if this worked for your original question please click the accpt button and ask a new question. keep it to one issue/question per post to make the answers easier to find by people who are looking for them in the future. If you want to post a link to your new question here after you accpt the answer i will look at it nad help you out.